# i want to replace a different word in every file at the same position in sublime text 3 using regex

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

I  want to replace the word at the position of 'Adarsh' in every file to a same word. please tell me the regular expression for this.
Input:-

```
<?php $page = 'Adarsh'; include('assets/services.php'); ?>
```

Outut:-

```
<?php $page = 'Raj'; include('assets/services.php'); ?>
```

'Raj' will be same in every file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could use `(?<=\$page\s=\s').+?(?=')` with the find and replace

Edit:

More specific `(?<=\$page\s=\s').+?(?=';\sinclude\('assets/services\.php)`

Comment: i want something specific like i want to replace it in the line in which assets/services.php is present only

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia Edited

Comment: thankyou very much but what should i write in replace ? to achieve <?php $page = 'Raj'; include('assets/services.php'); ?> in every file.

Comment: Use Find and Replace (Ctrl+H) Make sure the regex option is on. Put the regex in the Find text box and the word you want in the replace text box and press relace all

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia Or you could use (Ctrl+Shift+F) To search multiple files

Comment: Thankyou very much, and you are great. i have been trying to solve this problem from last 12 hours.

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia `<\?php\s*\$page\s*=\s*'.*?';\s.*?\('assets/services\.php'\);\s*\?>`

Comment: Thankyou very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Hii @tom-powis i need your help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714335/i-want-to-delete-a-word-on-a-specific-position-in-every-matching-phrase-using-re